# Backgroundworker.Reportprogress issues

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have some issues with my bgworker. What I'm trying to accomplish is that my bgworker reports the progress of unpacking a zip file into my textbox. 
This is how I want to show it:
5%
10%
15%
20%
25%
and so on.

This is what i´ve got so far:

```
int percentage;
percentage = count*100/array.Length;
worker.ReportProgress(percentage);
```

My textbox name is `ContentTextBox`.

This is the rest of the code that might be useful:

```
    private void UnpackBackgroundWorkerCompletedEvent(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                FileTextBox.Text = databaseName;
                ContentPanel.Visible = true;
                Text = "Check Database";

            }

            public void UnpackWorker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
            {
                if (FileTextBox.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File textbox is empty");
                    return;
                }

                String fileName = FileTextBox.Text;
                if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist");
                    return;
                }

                Logger logger = new Logger(Path.ChangeExtension(FileTextBox.Text, ".log"), this, ContentTextBox);

                String status = "******** Unpacking zipfile '" + fileName + "' ";
                logger.Write("");
                logger.Write("********");
                logger.Write(status);
                logger.Write("********");

                string databaseFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".db");
                DatabaseUtils.RestoreDatabase(fileName, databaseFileName);
                logger.Write("Zipfile '" + fileName + "' unpacked to '" + databaseFileName + "'.");

                databaseName = databaseFileName;




            }

public void Run()
        {
            var unpackWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

            if (FileTextBox.Text.EndsWith(".zip"))
            {
                unpackWorker.DoWork += UnpackWorker;
                unpackWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                unpackWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += UnpackBackgroundWorkerCompletedEvent;
            }
            else
            { MessageBox.Show("No zip selected")
            }

        }
```

**Edit**
To write into a textbox I have to use logger.Write()
because I make a logfile of the zip unpacking output.

Thanks for your help/advice in advance

Comment: You said you're having issues but you did not specify what those issues were.

Comment: What im trying to do is show the percentage in my textbox.

Comment: `DatabaseUtils.RestoreDatabase(fileName, databaseFileName);` should be modified to report progress.

Comment: I seen same question recently, can't find it. To have percents displayed you need to have `Progress` event of whatever `Zip` library you are using. In this event you can estimate how much work is done and display it. Otherwise you can simply say "Unzipping 0%" and then "Unzipping 100%" when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` Event and in it update your textbox.  Also you probably should be adding the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler before calling `RunWorkerAsync()`, to avoid a potential race condition.

```
unpackWorker.DoWork += UnpackWorker;
unpackWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += UnpackBackgroundWorkerCompletedEvent;
unpackWorker.ProgressChanged += SomeMethodThatUpdatesYourTextBox
unpackWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```